# how display data from two different tables in mysql pdo?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables projects and category. projects have pid, pname, catid and category have catid and catname.
i want display pname and catname. basically project name with category.
Please help

Comment: This needs trivial JOIN.

Comment: can you suggest a query. i am new in sql

Comment: I do NOT see any your attempts to solve your task. If you won't try you'll be new in SQL always.

Comment: i tried with left join. but i didn't hear about trivial join

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might like to format the code in your question with ``. That way, it wil be more readble.